# How can a WPF Canvas child's attached top/bottom/left/right property be removed?

Tags: wpf, canvas, attached-properties

Perhaps I am missing something simple here, but I am unable to find a method to remove an attached property from a item contained by a canvas.

Code example:

```
//Add an image to a canvas; set the location to the top
theCanvas.Children.Add(theImage);
Canvas.SetTop(theImage, 0);

//Move the image to the bottom of the canvas
Canvas.SetBtoom(theImage, 0);
```

This doesn't work since the Top attached property takes precedence over Bottom attached property; so we try to "unset" the top attached property

```
//Move the image to the bottom of the canvas
Canvas.SetTop(theImage, DependencyProperty.UnsetValue);
Canvas.SetBtoom(theImage, 0);
```

...and the compiler complains that UnsetValue can't be converted to a double.

What am I missing here and how do we remove the Top attached property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove local DepenendencyProperty values with ClearValue:

```
theImage.ClearValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
```

or inside a DependencyObject's code to remove the value from itself:

```
ClearValue(Canvas.TopProperty, theImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

From [`Canvas.Top` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.top.aspx):

> The default value is [NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx).

Try setting `Canvas.SetTop(theImage, double.NaN);`, this must help.

Comment: This may work in this case but is not a good solution in general. It both requires finding the default value and also overrides any method of value determination with a lower priority than Local (i.e. inherited or Styled values).